# IntelliJ plugin: how to use a custom FrameTitleBuilder?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to change the text in the IntelliJ main window, which normally looks like this:

```
myservice - [c:\some\path] - [myservice-webservice] - ...\a\b\c\foo.xml - IntelliJ IDEA 12-1-4
```

And I would like to use the maven version number, so that it will look like this:

```
myservice-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT - [c:\some\path] - [myservice-webservice] - ...\a\b\c\foo.xml - IntelliJ IDEA 12-1-4
```

There are no extension points from the plugin.xml that are apparent to me and when looking at the community edition code on github I got completely lost after looking through `ServiceManager` and `ApplicationManager`...

My conclusion was that a custom `FrameTitleBuilder` looks promising, but I can't see how to plug it in.

Or of course there may be a better way to do this.

Thanks for any tips on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the component in the PicoContainer, which is available from `ApplicationManager.getApplication().getPicoContainer()`, and then you just cast it to MutablPicoContainer to unregister and register the component.

If there's a better way, please add an answer or a comment!